# Hard drive is reported as BAD by SMART; how do I save it?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, clone

On boot, SMART is reporting my main HD as having a status of 'bad' and that I should backup and replace it.

It managed to boot into Windows after that, but I'm going to play it safe and replace the drive anyways.

Is there a way to 'clone' the contents of the failing drive onto a new one? It's important to note a couple of things

1. I do not have Windows install CDs since the installation of 10 that I've got now came via the free Win 10 upgrade.
2. I dual boot, and GRUB just happens to be installed on the failing drive.

Comment: You can clone one disk into another, we have many questions detailing how to do it. You also don't need a Windows CD as you can simply download the installer from Microsoft and write it to a memory stick if you want to do a clean install. If you do go for a clean install you just need to "skip" entering a product key and it should retrieve your digital entitlement for that machine from the internet. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

Comment: @Mokubai: Your comment is answer-quality.

Comment: @harrymc not really, I haven't given any information on *how* to clone a disk, only that we should have questions already. The rest of my comment is simply addressing his concern about needing an install disk which feels like a secondary concern. I can write an answer along similar lines, but of itself my comment does not directly address the question IMO. Will put pen to paper giving some options shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you actually have a few different options, depending on your personal preference.

1. You can get a new drive, install a clean version of Windows (and Linux) on it and then have your dying drive as a secondary disk to copy data off in your own time.
2. You can do a complete clone of your disk from your old disk to your new disk using a tool such as Macrium Reflect, Clonezilla or other similar tools. I've used Macrium in the past and it has a free trial period that can get you through the copying a disk stage.
3. You can do a mix of the above, installing Windows cleanly, then cloning your old disk data partition into a different partition in the new disk.

If you do go for any of the options then you'll need to be very careful about which disk you install Windows on and which you clone to which.

Personally I prefer option 1 as you can simply disconnect the old dying disk while you install Windows, and then reconnect it (on a SATA slot number above your new drive) and then copy the data off in slow time.

If you do go for a clean install then also don't need a Windows CD as you can simply download the installer from Microsoft and write it to a USB stick using their "Media Creation" tool. When installing you just need to "skip" entering a product key and it should retrieve your digital entitlement for that machine from the internet. [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)